# Finding the bitrate of source

Tags: arithmetic

I am doing a math homework but I'm not understanding one part of the question. What would be the 32 intensity values in following question:

> Suppose that a digitized TV picture is to be transmitted from a source
>   that uses a matrix 480x500 pictures elements (pixels), where each
>   pixel can take on one of 32 intensity values. Assume that 30 pictures
>   are sent per second. Find the source rate R (bps)

I have found the answer [here](http://faraday.elec.uow.edu.au/subjects/autumn/ECTE483/Tutorial%202%20solution.pdf) but I'm struggling figure out what does intensity values mean.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near as I can tell, it doesn't matter what "intensity level" means so much as that there are 32 possible states for each pixel, so you need enough space/bandwidth to indicate which of those 32 states each pixel is in.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are $32$ intensity levels and each pixel can have one of these levels.So each pixel will take 5 bits to represent itself(as $32=2^5$).Now one picture =$480\times 500$ pixels
$30$ pictures per second =$480\times 500\times 30$ pixels will be needed to sent per second and as each pixel need $5$ bits So total no. of bits to be sent per second=$480\times 500\times 30\times 5 $